# Bootstrap 4 - Modal. Working in Edge, not in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, .net-core, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

This example which is using the example from the website, works perfectly in Edge.  Both the remote call or `HTML` injection options in the `javascript` works.

In Chrome, the screen greys over button `onclick`, and HTML injection method and remote injection method works but the modal is not displayed.

CSS shows in _modal.scss: `.Modal { display: None; }`

...and in_transitions.scss: `.fade:not(.show) { opacity: 0; }`.

If I remove these two properties i see the modal.

In Firefox, same as Chrome.

Javascript:

```
<script>

    $( '#exampleModal' ).on( 'show.bs.modal', function ( e ) {

        var button = $( e.relatedTarget );
        var modal = $( this );

        // load content from HTML string
        modal.find( '.modal-body' ).html( "Nice modal body baby..." );
        console.log( button.data( "url" ) );
        // or, load content from value of data-remote url
        //modal.find('.modal-body').load(button.data("url"));

    } );

</script>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="margin-bottom: 10px" data-url="@Url.Action("_ClientDetails", new { PolicyTransactionNo = Model.PolicyTransactionNo })">
View Client Details
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

so, I replicated your code and the modal shows in chrome and firefox.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">



  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">



  <title>Hello, world!</title>


</head>


 <body>


 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="margin-bottom: 10px" data-url="@Url.Action("_ClientDetails", new { PolicyTransactionNo = Model.PolicyTransactionNo })">


   View Client Details
  </button>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
            aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1">


<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">


<div class="modal-content">


  <div class="modal-header">


  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
                  aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>


   </div>


  <div class="modal-body">



 </div>


  <div class="modal-footer">


   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>


 </div>


</div>


</div>


</div>



 <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 <script 
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" 
   integrity="sha384- 
   ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384- 
     JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
     crossorigin="anonymous">
     </script>



 <script>

        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

            var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
            var modal = $(this);

            // load content from HTML string
            modal.find('.modal-body').html("Nice modal body baby...");
            console.log(button.data("url"));
            // or, load content from value of data-remote url
            //modal.find('.modal-body').load(button.data("url"));

        });

    </script>



 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Curious, that is somewhat positive, but doesn't explain what is conflicting with it.  The page itself is huge, so picked out the parts of interest.  Does it matter where the actual modal div is?

Comment: i don't think it matters where the modal div is placed but have you checked whether you have other styles conflicting with the modal styling?

Comment: I now have it showing over the browsers but the formatting isn't good.  It looks like it is very sensitive to the various css/js scripts I have.  Edge being less sensitive than Firefox/Chrome.  Will now spend hours reordering and adding/removing to get it working on all with a nice appearance.  Thanks, will vote up as you got me past the code itself, which I already spent hours on.

Comment: Great. i wish you great luck!

Comment: Just for the benefit of future readers, I tried everything every which way on what is a complex page with many libraries being called with many views.  In the end, it was clear that the modal was left as Display: None, and the Fade was visable in Firefox/Edge.  I don't know why it works, but removing the Fade then resolved the issue and the modal as viewable.  Note it wasn't shown underneath which is another common issue.